# How to make pandas read rows in excel in the same order?

Tags: excel, pandas, dataframe, import

In general, when we import an excel file to pandas as a data frame, the order of the rows is different from the order of the rows in the excel sheet. I want the rows of the data frame to be the same as the rows in that of the excel sheet.

Answer (score 1):

Without looking at any code my guess is you have a `parsing` issue with pandas. You can try

```
arx=pd.ExcelFile("yourExcel.xlsx);
//specify your sheets here 
parsed = pd.io.excel.ExcelFile.parse(arx, "Sheet1");
```

If you can show your code, I may be able to help out a bit more 
[pandas parse](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/generated/pandas.read_excel.html)

Comment: You're missing the end quote to yourExcel.xlsx, I can't edit that few characters

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to do but when I had the same issue I used the df.columns to get the order that is in the excel sheet. You can now put it in a list with the correct order.

```
workbook = ExcelFile('myfile.xlsx')
df = workbook.parse('sheet1')
df_index = list(df.columns) #puts the col index in a list with correct order
```

lets say you know the column header and want the column number.

```
df_index.index('column header')
```

Hope this helped because it really helped me.